# Number of special pairs in n

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Considering pairs (a,b) with a+b = 4622 and neither a nor b divisible by 2,3,5,7,11.

Can anyone explain, and/or direct me to,the maths behind the fact that the first 2310 such pairs in n=4622 (as an example), contains exactly (5-2)*(7-2)*(11-2) pairs where neither a nor b are divisible by [2,3,5,7,11]  ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sequence $S$ of $2310=2\times 3\times 5\times 7\times 11$
consecutive numbers then they will be congruent to the numbers from
$0$ to $2310-1$ modulo $2310$ in some order. By the Chinese Remainder
Theorem an element of $S$ will be determined by its values modulo $2$,
modulo $3$, modulo $5$, modulo $7$ and modulo $11$. Call these $a_2$, $a_3$ etc. For $a$ to be indivisible by $2$, $3$, $5$ etc., we need
$a_p\not\equiv0\pmod p$ for all these $p$.

Here you have $b_p$, which depends on $a_p$ as $a_p+b_p\equiv4622\pmod{2310}$. For say $p=5$ we have these possible pairs for $(a_p,b_p)$:
$(0,2)$, $(1,1)$, $(2,0)$, $(3,4)$ and $(5,4)$. Two of these can be eliminated to have $5\nmid a$ and $5\nmid b$. This leaves $5-2=3$
possibles. Do this for all $p$ and multiply the results.

Comment: So kind....Thank you !!  Are you able to cite me a good reference for the math closely related to this particular kind of problem at all?

Comment: Pretty much any textbook on elementary number theory will deal with the Chinese Remainder Theorem. The version here is that a bunch of congruences $x\equiv a_i\pmod{n_i}$ for pairwise coprime $n_1,\ldots,n_k$ has a simultaneous solution, which is unique modulo $n_1\cdots n_k$.

Comment: Thank you again for your answers and kind references.